# Why am I getting an "expected expression error" when adding two floats in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

Why am I getting an "expected expression error" when adding two floats in Objective-C?

```
float animinum = 0.1 
animinum = animinum + %0.2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure what you want is:

```
animinum = animinum + 0.2;
```

And as rmaddy pointed out, you can shorten this to this:

```
animinum += 0.2;
```

Comment: Or just `animinum += 0.2;`

Comment: @rmaddy Indeed, my intent was to help him notice the difference. If he had trouble with a simple mistake like this I didn't want to confuse him further with compound operators ;) Nonetheless, I'll incorporate your edit into my answer if you don't mind.